# How to select most recent record from a group of records that have the same datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

So I have some records that I'm trying to display in a graph. Currently if some records have the same datetime then they get grouped in the graph which is kind of what I want, but the graph shows the sum of these records instead of the last record but I'm just not sure on how to achieve this.

`SUM(TAB.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY TAB.AccountID  order by TAB.AccountID, TransactionValueDate, StatementNumber, SequenceNumber, TAB.RecordID) AS [IntraDayBalance]`

This is the code I use to get these records which works perfect in the table but I can't use this in the graph as like I said it sums the records. So would there be a way to take the last record from this column that have the same datetime.

Not sure how to format this but this is an example. Let's say I have 3 records (532255.20 , 2199722.65 and 1995722.65) that have the exact same datetime (16/04/2019 06:41:04). Currently at this datetime point the graph shows me the summed figure of these records (4727700.5‬0) but what I actually want it to show is the last record (1995722.65).

What I'm asking then is how would I display this last record instead of the summed amount. Keep in mind I can't change the line of code shown above as it works perfect for it's original use just not for the graph so another line will be needed for the graph, I just have no idea how to do it myself. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Thank you for your help. I feel like an idiot right now but I'm just unable to incorporate either of these statements into my code. I'm still quite new to T-SQL and still learning how to format code properly and where things go but this is my SELECT statement, any tips on how to incorporate either of these statements into this code would be very helpful!

````
        ,TAB.AccountID
        ,TAB.Amount
        ,AC.ShortName
        ,FX.FXRate
        ,FX.IsDivide
        ,CASE 
            WHEN FXRate IS NOT NULL AND FXRate <> 0 THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN FX.IsDivide = 0 THEN
                        ROUND(TAB.Amount / FXRate,2)
                    ELSE
                        ROUND(TAB.Amount * FXRate,2)
                END
            ELSE
                0
        END AS BalanceUSD
        ,ITS.LimitAmount
        ,ITS.FloorAmount
        ,CR.SwiftCode AS Ccy
        ,TAB.RecordType
        ,AC.AccountNumber
        ,AC.BankFileIdentifier AS Accountidentifier
        ,DV.ShortName AS Division
        ,CP.ShortName AS Counterparty
        ,TAB.Amount
        ,SUM(TAB.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY TAB.AccountID  order by TAB.AccountID, TransactionValueDate, StatementNumber, SequenceNumber, TAB.RecordID) AS [IntraDayBalance]
        ,CAST(29218 + TransactionValueDate AS DATETIME) AS TransactionValueDate
        ,CAST(29218 + TransactionEntryDate AS DATETIME) AS TransactionEntryDate
        ,CASE
            WHEN TransactionFlow = 0 THEN
                TransactionAmount
            ELSE
                -TransactionAmount
        END AS TransactionAmount
        ,CASE 
            WHEN ITS.TransactionFlow = 0 THEN
                ITS.TransactionAmount
            ELSE
                0
        END AS Inflow
        ,CASE 
            WHEN ITS.TransactionFlow = 1 THEN
                ITS.TransactionAmount
            ELSE
                0
        END AS Outflow
        ,TransactionFlow
        ,TransactionCode
        ,CustomerReference
        ,BankReference
        ,Right(RTRIM('0000000000' + CAST(StatementNumber AS CHAR (20))), 10) AS StatementNumber
        ,RTRIM(CAST(ITS.SequenceNumber AS CHAR (20))) AS SequenceNumber
        ,CAST(29218 + StatementDate AS DATETIME) AS StatementDate
        --,DATEADD(SECOND,ImportedByTime,CAST(29218 + StatementDate AS DATETIME))  AS StatementDateTime
        ,CASE
            WHEN TAB.RecordType = 'B' THEN
                @StartDate
            ELSE
                DATEADD(SECOND,ImportedByTime,CAST(29218 + StatementDate AS DATETIME))  
        END AS StatementDateTime
        ,InformationToAccountOwner
        ,Information1
        ,Information2
        ,Information3
        ,Information4
        ,Information5
        ,Information6
        ,ImportedBy
        ,CAST(29218 + ImportedByDate AS DATETIME) AS ImportedByDate
        ,CASE
            WHEN TAB.RecordType = 'B' THEN
                @StartDate
            ELSE
                DATEADD(SECOND,ImportedByTime,CAST(29218 + ImportedByDate AS DATETIME))  
        END AS ImportDateTime
        ,@StartDate AS StartDate
        ,@EndDate AS EndDate
        ,ITS.DebitAmount
        ,ITS.CreditAmount
        ,ITS.FloorAmount
        ,ITS.LimitAmount
        ,ITS.RecordID


FROM CTE_TransactionsAndBalances AS TAB

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    InterimTransactionStatement AS ITS ON TAB.RecordID = ITS.RecordID

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Accounts AS AC ON TAB.AccountID = AC.ACRecordID

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Currencies AS CR ON AC.CurrencyID = CR.CRRecordID

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Divisions AS DV ON AC.DivisionID = DV.DVRecordID

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Counterparties AS CP ON AC.CounterpartyID = CP.CPRecordID

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    @tbl_FXRates AS FX ON AC.CurrencyID = FX.FromCcyID
    AND FXRateDateN >= FX.StartDateN
    AND FXRateDateN <= FX.EndDateN
    AND FX.ToCcyID = @ReportingCcyID

--WHERE AC.ACRecordID = 94
 order by TAB.AccountID, TransactionValueDate, StatementNumber, SequenceNumber, TAB.RecordID ```
````

Answer (score 0):

use subquery and `row_numberr()`

```
select * from ( select
SUM(TAB.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY TAB.AccountID  order by TAB.AccountID, TransactionValueDate, StatementNumber, SequenceNumber, TAB.RecordID) AS [IntraDayBalance],
row_number() over(partition by TAB.AccountID order by TransactionValueDate desc) rn
from table
) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: Hi, I edited my question as I'm still somewhat confused. Could you have a look and help me out once again, much appreciated!